# Assigning Integer Value to String. Android/Java

Tags: java, android, string, view, integer

I'm new to both Java and Android and I was working on a program where it has two EditText's in a row. The first edittext I want to be a string and the second an integer which is assigned to that string.

To make it more specific, the user inputs Homework and 15 and I want this number to be saved such that in the future when a user inputs an assignment into Homework with a value, that value multiplies with 15.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
             android:id="@+id/register_assign_edit"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:gravity="center_horizontal"
             android:hint="@string/example_assign"
             android:singleLine="true"
             android:inputType="textCapWords"
             android:layout_weight="1">
         </EditText>

        <EditText
             android:id="@+id/register_weight_edit"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:hint="@string/example_weight"
             android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
             android:gravity="center_horizontal"
             android:inputType="number"
             android:singleLine="true"
             android:maxLength="2">
         </EditText>        

</LinearLayout>
```

That's my xml file

This is my .java file

```
public void onAddNewClicked(View v){
        inflateEditRow(null, null);
        v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    private void inflateEditRow(String name, String name1){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_class, null);

        final EditText register_assign = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.register_assign_edit);
        final EditText register_weight = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.register_weight_edit);

        if (name != null && !name.isEmpty()) {
            register_assign.setText(name);
            register_weight.setText(name1);
        } else {
            mExclusiveEmptyView = rowView;
        }
          mContainerView.addView(rowView, mContainerView.getChildCount()-1);
    }
```

I tried to change the parameter of String name2 to Integer weight and when I called it in OnAddNewClicked as inflateEditRow(null, (Integer) null), the program is crashing.

Comment: Your method accepts both parameters of type `String`. You can't pass an `Integer` to it. Why exactly are you typecasting `null` to `Integer`?

Comment: One more thing name1 isn't checked for null before it used

Answer (score 0):

To convert a `String` containing an expected integer value, use:

```
Integer.valueOf(yourString);
```

Bear in mind you will have to try-catch your conversion, since if the original `String` does not consist of a valid integer value, a `NumberFormatException` will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Just use integer and set the EditText like this:

```
 private void inflateEditRow(String name, int number) {

    //... your code

    register_weight.setText(""+number);
    //... your code
 }
```

If you want to get an Integer value from the EditText, call

```
int myinteger = Integer.valueOf(edittext.getText().toString());
```

But make sure the EditText only contains Integer values, otherwise your app will crash.

Answer (score 0):

1. Casting `null` to any type - like you do with `Integer` is useless. Invoking `inflateEditRow(null, null)` is the same (unless you want to fish for `ClassCastException`) before invoking it.
2. If you want to convert an `Integer` to just call `Integer.toString()` or append an empty `String` ("") to it, like `String intString = yourInteger + "";`. Or you can use `String.valueOf(anInteger)`.
   If you want to parse an `Integer` from `String` use `Integer.parseInt(aString)`. However, you might want to check for `NumberFormatException`.